# how to eliminate trailing newlines and store the result in variables

Tags: bash, sed, escaping, backslash, single-quotes

As the title says, I want to eliminate trailing newlines and store the result in variables (Bash).

The following does not work.

```
[xxx@ ~]$ var=`echo 'abc\ndef\n' | sed 's/\\n$//g'`
[xxx@ ~]$ echo $var
abc\ndef\n
```

The following works!

```
[xxx@ ~]$ var=`echo 'abc\ndef\n' | sed 's/\\\\n$//g'`
[xxx@ ~]$ echo $var
abc\ndef
```

I thought that only one backslash escape was needed for sed since it is enclosed in single quotes, but I guess my understanding is wrong.

Please tell me why the second command works correctly?

Comment: As per the [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Command-Substitution) for `$()` and `\`` operators: "Bash performs the expansion by executing command in a subshell environment and replacing the command substitution with the standard output of the command, **with any trailing newlines deleted**." So you don't need to do anything more to eliminate trailing newlines.

Comment: Also, newlines are a special character in sed, they won't be in the buffer unless you use `sed -z`.

Comment: `bash`'s version of `echo` isn't producing any newlines in that command.

Comment: You're not removing newlines, you're removing a plain backslash character followed by the letter "n". That sequence is sometimes used to represent a newline, but that's not what it's doing here.

Comment: It was my mistake to describe \n in the sample as newlines.
Sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding:

> Please tell me why the second command works correctly?

This command produces the shown output:

```
$ echo 'abc\ndef\n' | sed 's/\\\\n$//g'
abc\ndef\n
```

As for why you get this unexpected output with old, deprecated backticks:

```
$ var=`echo 'abc\ndef\n' | sed 's/\\\\n$//g'`
$ echo "$var"
abc\ndef
```

which is different from this expected output with modern command substitution (`$(...)`):

```
$ var=$(echo 'abc\ndef\n' | sed 's/\\\\n$//g')
$ echo "$var"
abc\ndef\n
```

it's because backslashes (`\`) inside backticks are handled in a non-obvious manner as stated and demonstrated at the top of the related FAQ, https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082, and that is one of the reasons to use `$(...)` instead of backticks to execute commands.

So, if you want to remove a trailing `\n` string using a pipe to `sed` then do this:

```
$ var=$(echo 'abc\ndef\n' | sed 's/\\n$//g')
$ echo "$var"
abc\ndef
```

otherwise, if you really want to remove newlines as your Subject line says then read on:

`echo 'abc\ndef\n'` produces this output:

```
$ echo 'abc\ndef\n'
abc\ndef\n
```

The only newline present in that output is the one at the end of the line that makes that a valid POSIX text file. The `\n`s are literally the 2 characters `\` and `\n`.

You should use `printf` instead of `echo` for portability and consistency. In this case it would convert `\n` strings to newlines:

```
$ printf 'abc\ndef\n'
abc
def
```

Now, to get RID of the newlines - sed by default reads input 1 line at a time so you can't remove a newline from a string that sed sees as there cannot be a newline within 1 line that's part of newline-separated input. You can do things with sed to make it read multiple lines but it's more robust and portable to use awk instead, e.g.:

to remove just the final newline:

```
$ printf 'abc\ndef\n' | awk '{printf "%s%s", sep, $0; sep=ORS}'
abc
def             <--- no newline at the end
```

or to remove all newlines:

```
$ printf 'abc\ndef\n' | awk -v ORS= '1'
abcdef          <--- no newline at the end
```

or to remove all except the final newline:

```
$ printf 'abc\ndef\n' | awk -v ORS= '1; END{print RS}'
abcdef          <--- newline at the end
```

or similar depending on whether you want the string to end in a newline (and so be a valid POSIX text line/file) or not.

To execute a command, store it's result in a variable, and then print the contents of that variable, one way using command substitution would be:

```
$ var=$(printf 'abc\ndef\n' | awk -v ORS= '1; END{print RS}')
$ printf '%s\n' "$var"
abcdef
```

Note the use of `$(...)` instead of the long deprecated backticks (https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082), and the necessary quotes `"..."` around the shell variable (see https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes). Get into the habit of copy/pasting your code into http://shellcheck.net and it'll help you find and fix errors.